# Twitter bootstrap hex to rgba?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, alpha

Let a *color* variable used in `sheet.less`.

*color* is in HEX format `#f57e20`.

I want to use that *color* but add an alpha channel to it.

I want to end up with `rgba(245, 126, 32, 0.5)`

Does ***Bootstrap*** or ***less*** have anything to do this?

Answer (score 20):

There are a some **built in functions** in `less.js` and **mixins** from *Bootstrap* that you could use:

This is a `less.js` function:

```
// using a variable

@color: #f57e20;

.test {
  background: fade(@color, 50%); // return @color with 50% transparency
}

// or without the color variable

.test2 {
  background: fade(#f57e20, 50%); // return @color with 50% transparency
}
```

These both result in:

```
.test {
  background: rgba(245, 126, 32, 0.5);
}
.test2 {
  background: rgba(245, 126, 32, 0.5);
}
```

Or use a *Bootstrap* mixin:

```
.test3 {
  #translucent > .background(#f57e20, 0.5); // use HSLA mixin
}
```

Which results in:

```
.test3 {
  background-color: rgba(244, 123, 31, 0.5);
}
```

I'll include the (fixed) code for the `translucent` mixins here for archiving purposes, since (last I checked) it is no longer included as of *Bootstrap 3.0.0*:

```
// Add an alphatransparency value to any background or border color (via Elyse Holladay)
#translucent {
  .background(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {
    background-color: fade(@color, @alpha);
  }
  .border(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {
    border-color: fade(@color, @alpha);
    .background-clip(padding-box);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try:

```
background: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha);
```

I had to do something similar when writing a quick mixin which used box-shadow.

Comment: Works quite well without any mixin! Bootstrap 3.3.

Comment: @el-teedee No, because this bloating `rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha)` has *no* advantages over the proper `fade(@color, @alpha);` of the accepted answer.

Comment: @seven-phases-max here is the advantage I see: 

I successfully obtained my alpha background using `background-color: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @opacity);` because my framework uses Bootstrap, but NOT `less.js` for compilation, thus getting exception `no viable alternative at input 'fade' in abstract mixin or namespace (which started at 22:1)` when using instead `fade(@color, @opacity);`. 

Sounds like an advantage from my place ;)

Comment: @el-teedee - `fade` function is the part of the Less language. If your framework does not support it then it has nothing todo with Less. Thus it's just some exotic stuff you have there and it's barely to guide which answer to be accepted or not.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake during first try. I finally ended with `fade` working with no exception sumarized with `@myColor: fade(red, 30%);

.myMixin ( @color: transparent; @opacity: 80%) {
  background-color: @color;
}

.myComponent1() { .myMixin(@color1, 70%); }

.myComponent2() { .myMixin(@color2, 40%); }
`